# gcc std=gnu++0x option

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, build

I need to compile a C++ code that uses std=gnu++0x option to the g++ compiler in the Makefile.am , As this option is compatible only with gcc 4.3 and above, the build crashes on my machine where i have gcc 4.2.

What are my alternatives ? I tried removing that option from the Makefile.am but that reports some other error. Do i need to install gcc 4.3 or above? How can I do it in ubuntu hardy through apt-get ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, upgrade your Ubuntu. A new LTS (10.04) is just about ready for release.

I you are really desperate, try [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain/+archive/ppa) (not for the faint of heart).

Comment: Sill me; off by one. I've removed the 7.10 comment.